# Need help with a survey word problem...

Tags: word-problem

I am unable to solve this problem in attached screen shot and need help

[image]

Comment: The sum of the two entries in the zumba column is $94$.  It doesn't say that they all chose rock climbing.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Please ignore the pencil writings

Comment: Then tell us how far you've gotten with this problem.  What are your thoughts?  What have you done?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Its really tough to type it here so i posted an answer. I am not sure if its correct. Can you help take a look at it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Not sure if its correct

Imaging rock climbing & circuit = rc

rock climbing & zumba = rz

treadmill & circuit = tc

treadmill & zumba = tz

since there are 200 participants 
rc + rz + tc + tz = 200
since rc = 76
76 + rz + tc + tz = 200
rz + tc + tz = 200 - 76 = 124

since 94 chose zumba so we have tz + rz = 94

94 + tc = 124

tc = 124 - 94 = 30

Now from 
[image]

￼
if tc = 30, then tz is twice the tc and that makes tz = 60

so until now tc = 30, tz = 60, rc = 76

and rc + rz + tc + tz = 200

76 + rz + 30 + 60 = 200

rz = 200 - 76 - 30 - 60

rz = 34

Finally tc = 30, tz = 60, rc = 76, rz = 34

Comment: Looks right to me.